# Как оставлять закрытые картинки закрытыми с помощью React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть 2 компоненты, в первую приходит массив объектов, которая преобразует их и выводит блоки с картинками, у меня добавлен прослушиватель событий на кнопку, который закрывает блок, мне нужно, чтобы при перезагрузке браузера закрытый блок оставался закрытым, как это можно сделать?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
import axios from "axios";
import s from './Card.module.css'

let Cards = (props) => {
    const[active,setActive] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://contest.elecard.ru/frontend_data/catalog.json').then((responce) => {
            props.setCards(responce.data);

        })
    },[active])
    let card = props.cards.map(c => active ? <Card active={active} setActive={setActive} image={c.image} filesize={c.filesize} key={c.id}/> : null)
    return (
        <div className={s.cardContainer}>
            {card}

        </div>
    )
}
export default Cards;
```

Вот вторая компонента

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import s from './Card.module.css'
import './Card.css'

let Card = (props) => {

    return (
        <div className={s.cardWrapper}>
            <img  className={s.image} src={`http://contest.elecard.ru/frontend_data/${props.image}`}
                 alt=""/>
            <div className={s.text}>
                Some text
            </div>
            <button onClick={(e) => {
                e.currentTarget.parentNode.classList.add('close');
            }} className={s.closeBtn}></button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: Сохранять значения в localStorage и проверять по нему отображение

Comment: Я понимаю, что нужно использовать localStorage, но не особо понимаю, как его использовать, я могу туда что-то передать, какое-то значение, а что дальше? И какое значение туда передавать.